# Styling text to make it appear above the line (for chords above the lyrics)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to show chords above the lyrics in music using CSS. This is what I'd really like it to look like:

```
C                                           F
This line has a C chord, and it also has an F chord
```

so that the chord changes are shown in the right places. In HTML it looks like this:

```
<span class="chord">C</span>This line has a C chord, and it also has an <span class="chord">F</span>F chord
```

And I managed to nearly get the effect with this styling:

```
.chord {
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
}
```

But the problem is that it has gaps:

```
C                                            F
 This line has a C chord, and it also has an  F chord
```

If only width:0 (which I would use with overflow:visible) worked on an inline span. Does anyone have a solution?

**Edit:** Solved thanks to @Kyle Sevenoaks. For anyone who's interested, here's my complete CSS, which allows verses to be marked with `<p>`, chords to be marked with `<span>` and whether chords are displayed to be toggled with the `show-chords` class on the parent div:

```css
p.song span {
  display: none;
}
p.song.show-chords p {
  line-height:2.3em;
  margin-bottom:2em;
}
p.song.show-chords span {
  position: relative;
  top: -1em;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  overflow:visible;
  text-shadow:#CCC -1px 1px;
  color:#00F;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="song show-chords">
  <span class="chord">C</span>This line has a C chord, and it also has an <span class="chord">F</span>F chord
</p>
```

Comment: have you ever tried adding also a left: 10px; ? or do you need a more flexible solution?

Comment: do you have any solution to make this stylesheet becomes mobile friendly? When i see it in my mobile phone, the chord is not at the right place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inline elements, you can use `display: inline-block;` to have it accept width. But for your problem, why not simply add `left: 3px; /*em or whatever*/`? It will indent it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `display: inline-block;` That's fixed it. I can't use `left:` because that still leaves the gaps in the text.

Comment: Well at least one solution helped you out :)

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, `position: relative` still reserves the space needed.

Here is a solution that wraps a `position: absolute` span around the relatively positioned one, so that the space does not get reserved any more:

```
 <span class="chord">
  <span class="inner">C</span>
 </span>This line has a C chord, and it also has an 
 <span class="chord">
  <span class="inner">F</span>
 </span>F chord
```

CSS:

```
.chord { position: absolute
 }

.chord .inner {  position: relative;
    top: -1em;}
```

The advantage over the `left` approach is that this will work for any chord width (think  <kbd>Esus</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd>.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g3jRc/). Tested in IE6,7,8, Chrome 6

Answer (score 6):

Here is a variant using `data-*` attributes and `:before` pseudoclass

HTML:

```
<span data-chord="C">T</span>his line has a C chord, and it 
also has an <span data-chord="F">F</span> chord
```

CSS:

```
span[data-chord]:before {
    position    : relative;
    top         : -1em;
    display     : inline-block;
    content     : attr(data-chord);
    width       : 0;
    font-style  : italic;
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/4wKkp/

Comment: This is quite an interesting way of doing it. It's like attaching a chord to a character instead of inserting it in somewhere. I've still gone for my original HTML structure because I do prefer it at the moment, but I'll keep this one in mind.

Comment: while I wrote this example I made some thoughts about semantic of this solution. It's true that without css enabled the information about chord is not accessible at all, but other solution like that you're using make lyrics less accessible since chord information 'breaks' the text. So I think there is not a unique solution. It depends.

Comment: Yes, but this will be used in a controlled environment where I can be sure that features will be supported. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle link, I've updated the example and increased aural accessibility. =) I will update it also next days If I come to a better idea.